# TIME AND WORK questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A and B can do a piece of work in 45 days and 40 days respectively. They began to do the work together but A leaves after some days and then B completed the remaining work in 23 days. The number of days after which A left the work was:

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A can do $\frac{1}{45}$ of work in one day and B can do $\frac{1}{40}$ of work in one day. so together they will do $\frac{1}{45}+\frac{1}{40}=\frac{17}{360}$ of work in one day. if we assume they worked $x$ days together and then the remaining work was done by $B$ in $23$ days. so we have this equation( this equation says for doing the whole job or $1$ in RHS, $A$ and $B$ worked $x$ days together and $B$ worked $23$ days alone in LHS):

$$\frac{17x}{360}+\frac{23}{40}=1 \Rightarrow 17x+207=360 \Rightarrow x= \frac{153}{17}=9$$
which means  $A$ left after $9$ days.